# Issue in calling javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, functional-programming

I need to call a function like function `share()` in javascript but the code is in jquery, how to call under this part of code in order to achieve pop up message...

javascript button function call code.

```
instance.addEventHandler(PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onToolbarTap, function(e){
                    if (e.toolbarAction === PhotoSwipe.Toolbar.ToolbarAction.none){
                            share();
                    }
                });
```

jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var dialog = $('#dialog');

        dialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $(".say-hi").bind('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :

```
$(".say-hi").click(); //instead of share();
```

Or you can wrap the jquery click as a function and then call `share();`

Comment: thanks for the ur reply, i have done like this http://jsfiddle.net/yHTJw/78/ please see this @Roy M J

Answer (score 0):

I put `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` before I call method and it works fine. You don't need to write document.ready again inside function.

function share(){

```
var dialog = $('#dialog');

    dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });


        e.preventDefault();
        dialog.dialog('open');

}
```

Comment: It will not run the last set of codes `$(".say-hi").bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dialog.dialog('open');
    });`

Comment: thanks for the reply i'm getting error as " Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at file" @Kuzgun

Comment: yes i have added the jquery library also "<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> " @Kuzgun